# Back4App Push notifications are without data

Tags: parse-platform, lua, push-notification, coronasdk, back4app

I use Back4App service to send push notifications. I managed to get push notifications to work, and they work from the client and from the server, but the problem is that all notifications come with the same format (title>name of the app, alert>name of the app).
I am sure I am changing the alert and the title text in the json, but still they are all sent with the app name.

This is my json table:

```
{
    "channels": [
      "TestChannel"
    ],
    "data": {
      "alert": "The Mets scored! The game is now tied 1-1.",
      "title": "Mets Score!"
    }
}
```

Here is how I call the function (using lua in corona SDK):

```
parse.request(parse.Push.send)
:data(pushJson)
:response(function(responseString, responseTable, errorTable)
    adjustResponseString("Sending Push", responseString, responseTable, errorTable)
end)
```

This is my current app name "ParseTest".
Here is what the notification looks like:
https://i.snag.gy/rXQ9Ja.jpg
(This is the case when I send push notifications from both client and server.)

Answer (score 0):

at the moment, I'll recommend to you work with Cloud Code Function (It works with JS SDK) and you can call it via your project app, the guides are:

- [What is Cloud Code function?](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions)
- You can send Pushes via your JS SDK using [this link](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#using-channels).